# Telerik ImageManager image preview not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I have a problem right now with the ImageManager, this is happening when the image name contains special characters like "$, %, &..." i already have the validation to not allow the user upload more images with special characters, but right now in the server there are some images that contains special chars and we need to load them too, so but the ImageManager is not workign with the preview when a special character is in the imagename, does anybody knows a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Given the telerik image manager will not load images with special characters in the name, you could create a simple function (most likely only to run once) which will rename the existing images on your server with prohibited characters with something else, e.g. replacing "$" with "_dollar_".

Going by my previous experience with the controls there are often work-arounds but sanitizing your existing data is always the preferable option as it prevents the necessity to perform extra processing.

Comment: I know i can rename the images and avoid the problem, but i can't do that since these images are used to send emails, so renaming images is the the solution, that's why i'm looking for a solution in the control to load images with special characters ...

Comment: I got the solution, this was caused by the APP Pool, so i just switch to Classic instead integrate and now is working just perfect :)